# Overriding function of a deployed contract

Tags: solidity

Suppose I have token contract which is already deployed into the network. I want to make change one of its function without redeploying it. How to do this? Is it possible to override its function?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly change the code of a deployed contract.

Depending on the code of the function you want to override, you *might* be able to create a wrapper contract to simulate a change in the code. Whether this is possible depends on the details of the change you want to make.